# Dropping the database in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
~/Rails Projects/QA-app$ rake db:drop
rake aborted!
Gem::LoadError: You have already activated rake 10.3.2, but your Gemfile requires rake 10.1.1. Using bundle exec may solve this.
/home/salmanalam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:33:in `block in setup'
/home/salmanalam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:19:in `setup'
/home/salmanalam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `setup'
/home/salmanalam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/setup.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/home/salmanalam/Rails Projects/QA-app/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/salmanalam/Rails Projects/QA-app/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/salmanalam/Rails Projects/QA-app/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: Can someone tell me what happened? And what can I do to get rid of this problem?

Comment: Try running it under bundle exec like it says? Seems a good place to start.

Comment: It says "Using bundle exec may solve this." so try `bundle exec rake db:drop`

Comment: I tried with bundle exec it did work, but seems like I have to enter bundle exec every time. Any answers to that?

Comment: Remove the non-bundle rake gem and install the version from the Gemfile.

Answer (score 2):

Run the command using bundle exec(`bundle exec rake db:drop`) to force the version of rake that is used by your application.

Answer (score 2):

Just run `bundle update and update your app. The version of Rake that it is looking for is 10.1.1 but your version of Rake has already been updated to 10.3.2

Answer (score 1):

You can't just go updating all gems willy nilly on a larger project without running into problems. If you don't want to have to prefix `bundle exec`, then just run `bundle update rake`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

```
rm -rf Gemfile.lock
```

Then run `bundle install` if needed, and `rake db:(whatever)` goes without error.